# Collecting extra information in the default asp.net-mvc registration form

Tags: asp.net-mvc

There are a few pieces of information I must collect when a user registers on my site.  What is an easy way to modify the default registration form to collect this extra information?

One idea I've read about is creating my own Profile provider, but I read that this can make the data quite hard to search and modify from an admin backend.

I'm sorry if I'm missing something basic, but I am extremely new to both asp.net-mvc and .net in general.

Answer (score 0):

There are better way's I am sure but here is what I do.

When the user has registered I redirect to another page/ActionResult where there are further details to fill in.

I haven't bothered with custom provider.  All I do is create another table that holds the extra information and I query that seperately.

Why have I done it that way?  Two reasons.  Firstly it's easy and the second reason is I like to keep my implementation of custom data seperate from the default provider data.

I'm sure there is a better way but this has worked for me on several sites so I'm quite happy at the moment.